# How to remove special characters from a xpath using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[image]

As you are able to see, I have used one dynamic xpath: `//td[text()='Discharge Air']/following-sibling::td/span` to go from zone1 until zone3, but when I am using gettext() to fetch only 100 but special character °F is also coming. Hence please suggest how to **remove this special character °F**, because I want only data 100 from this xpath? As you can see in the image, only 1 span is available, so I can't separate span also.

---

String s = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='Discharge Air']/following-sibling::td/span")).getText();

s.replace("°F","");//replace the °F with empty string

**Instead of String, can i use List because all these xpath are of same type,hence directly i can write and afterwards i can use for loop for getText().**

List s=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[text()='Discharge Air']/following-sibling::td/span"));

s.replace("°F","");

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Before the edit you mentioned a String and not a List so you should accept my answer right away. And now you can just aplly a foreach loop and do the same for all strings in the list

Answer (score 1):

List disch_Air = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[text()='Discharge Air']/following-sibling::td/span"));

```
 for(int i=0;i<disch_Air.size();i++) {
     
     System.out.println(disch_Air.get(i).getText().replace("°F", ""));
 }
    
    
     }
```

**This is what i want  and its working fine thank you so much guys for ur help**

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
//first find the elements and save it as you did (with the xpath you posted)

String s = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text()='Discharge Air']/following-sibling::td/span")).getText();

 s.replace("°F","");//replace the °F with empty string
```

and if you see that there are still spaces on your string you can use this to remove them:

```
s.trim();
```